# How to decode encoded query params in GET request using grape-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm using *grape-api* and having a problem with making a ***GET*** request from my front-end service with encoded query params. This is how my endpoint is set up to receive the params:

```
params do
  requires :event_id, type: String, desc: 'Event id'
  requires :tickets, type: Array, desc: 'Array of each ticket data ex:  [ {id: "", count: 1 , coupon_code: ""} ]', allow_blank: false do
    requires :id, type: String, desc: 'Ticket id'
    requires :count, type: Integer, desc: 'Number of tickets to get'
    optional :coupon_code, type: String, desc: 'Promocode to apply if any'
  end
end
```

As you can see I'm expecting an *event_id* param and another array of objects param *tickets*, and this is how the request URL looks like:

http://localhost:3000/api/service_fees/calculate?eventId=2xy6rft69azlu2mtppnzb1xe6olzd3f0&tickets[]=%7B%22id%22:%22vohd3y3n25cdgbvi3uzmqhcyie3zi53a%22,%22count%22:2%7D

however, grape doesn't seem to understand these encoded query params and I get this exception:

```
[Exception: event_id is missing, tickets[0][id] is missing, tickets[0][id] is invalid, tickets[0][count] is missing, tickets[0][count] is invalid]
```

my question is this: is there a way i can tell grape to decode and parse the query params properly? am i missing something here?

Comment: Can you show the server logs?

Comment: I don't see any `event_id` param in the URL you displayed. It is `eventId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:3000/api/service_fees/calculate?eventId=2xy6rft69azlu2mtppnzb1xe6olzd3f0&tickets[]=%7B%22id%22:%22vohd3y3n25cdgbvi3uzmqhcyie3zi53a%22,%22count%22:2%7D
```

For the above request URL, the parameter name sent is `eventID` whereas the Grape API requires/expects `event_id`. Also, the `tickets` URL Query String Parameters construction is wrong.

Can you try this instead -- `http://localhost:3000/api/service_fees/calculate?eventId=2xy6rft69azlu2mtppnzb1xe6olzd3f0&tickets[0][id] =12&tickets[0][count] =13&tickets[0][coupon_code]=amrrbakry`